# платная покупка

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь сделать в своем приложении покупку. При нажатии кнопки увеличивается int monetki и сохраняется в SharedPreferences.

Платеж проходит, деньги списываются, выдается оповещение об успешной покупке, но в приложении ничего не происходит. Через дебаг не могу проверить потому что это платная покупка. Что делать?

```
IabHelper mHelper;
    int monetki;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    String str;
    TextView change;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buy);
    sPref = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sPref.contains("monetki")) {
        monetki = sPref.getInt("monetki", 0);
    change = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.monviewbuy);
    String str = Integer.toString(monetki);
        change.setText(str);
    }




    String base64EncodedPublicKey;

    base64EncodedPublicKey = "...";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {

        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                //   Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
            }
            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
        }
    });
}

String mon15 = "monetki15";
public void click15(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, mon15, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, " ");
}

String mon40 = "monetki";
public void click40(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, mon40, 10002, mPurchaseFinishedListener, " ");

}

String mon120 = "monetki120";
public void click120(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, mon120, 10003, mPurchaseFinishedListener, " ");
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
  //          Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(mon120)) {
            monetki+=120;
            str = Integer.toString(monetki);
            change.setText(str);
            savemonetki(monetki);
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(mon40)) {
            monetki+=40;
            str = Integer.toString(monetki);
            change.setText(str);
            savemonetki(monetki);
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(mon15)){
            monetki+=15;
            str = Integer.toString(monetki);
            change.setText(str);
            savemonetki(monetki);
        }
    }
};

public boolean savemonetki(int monetki){
    sPref = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putInt("monetki", monetki);
    ed.commit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Через дебаг можно проверять платные покупки. Код в `result.isFailure()` закомментирован, где выдается оповещение об успешной покупке? Этот код вообще выполняется, в `TextView change` текст изменяется?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, что бы добавили обработку в `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mIabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Эта обработка обязательно должна быть в активности, а не во фрагменте, либо нужно вручную передавать результат во фрагмент.

Вы запускаете `launchPurchaseFlow()` с разными `resultCode`. Скорее всего, так делать нет смысла, достаточно одного кода.